# Multiple IFS in google sheet giving Formula Parse Error

Tags: google-sheets

I am trying to create an IELTS band calculator using Google Sheets. The conversions I am using are here in detail. https://ieltsliz.com/ielts-band-scores/

I want to enter the Listening raw score in Cell C2 and then have it populate the bands in H2 based on where it falls in the range. I am using IFS conditional to calculate the scores because there are some values that fall within a range.

However, I get the following error

```
Error
Formula parse error.
```

The IFS statement is below. I am not sure what I am doing wrong

```
=ifs(AND(C2>10, C2<=12), "4.0" , 
AND(C2>12,C2<=15), "4.5", 
AND(C2>15 C2<=17), "5.0" , 
AND(C2>17,C2<=22), "5.5", 
AND(C2>22,C2<=25), "6.0", 
AND(C2>25,C2<=29), "6.5" , 
AND(C2>29,C2<=31), "7.0" , 
AND(C2>31,C2<=34), "7.5" , 
AND(C2>34,C2>=36), "8.0" , 
AND(C2>36,C2<=38), "8.5" , 
AND(C2>38,C2<=40),"9.0" 
)
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: On line 3, you forgot a comma `AND(C2>15 C2<=17)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, get rid of all the quotation marks entirely.

Then read about the `Match()` function, which gets the same results in a significantly simpler way.

This formula, for example, should suffice:

```
=(MATCH(C2-.01; {10;12;15;17;22;25;29;31;34;36;38})-1)/2+4
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for this suggestion. I will read up on the LOOKUP function

Comment: If you're gonna go that route you might as well make a sheet for the IELTS codes.

Comment: @sanster9292 I edited the formula to further simplify.  Not sure why i went with LOOKUP() instead of MATCH()

Comment: Thanks Matt, this has been great help